# My Program is not efficient.Is there any shorter way to solve it?

Tags: javascript

Since I have just started Javascript, I am trying to solve a few problems and improve myself. I encountered such a question. I tried to do everything step by step from the question, but I do not think that my code is efficient. Can someone help me develop it?

QUESTION:

Please code for a JavaScript function that accepts two arguments that are; parking "date and time"(timestamp) and return "date and time"(timestamp).
At an airport for car parking, the following rules are applied.

Parking costs;

- €2 for the first 20 minutes,
- rising to €4 for up to 40 minutes,
- rising to €6 for up to one hour,
- rising to €7 for up to two hours,
- rising to €9 for up to three hours,
- rising to €11 for up to four hours,
- rising to €13 for 4-8 hours and
- rising to €15 for 8-24 hours.
- €16 for the first 24 hours and after that each additional day is
  charged at €9.

Here is my code:

```
    function msToHours(milisecond) {
        let time = milisecond;

        let hour = (time / 60000) / 60;

        return hour;
    }


    //Mins to Hours Function
    function minToHours(miniute){

        let time = miniute;

        let hr = (miniute /60);

        return hr;

    }


    //Finding the nth day Function

    function add24HR(hour, cb) {

        let arr = new Array();

        for (let i = 0; i < hour; i++) {
            if (i % 24 == 0) {
                arr.push(i)
            }
        }
    
        return  `Your Parking Fee is £${(arr.length*cb-cb) + 16}.(${arr.length} days)`
    }

    //Main Function

    const parkingFees = (parkingDate, returnDate) => {

        //Defining dates
        var park = new Date(parkingDate)
        var returned = new Date(returnDate);

        //Variables
        var penaltyFee = 9;
        let totalPrice;


        //Time between park and return (miliseconds)
        let totalTime = returned - park

        //MiliSeconds to Hour
        let totalPark = msToHours(totalTime);

        //Mins to Hours
        if (totalPark <= minToHours(20)) {
            return `Your parking fee is only £${2}.`
        } 

        else if(totalPark > minToHours(20) && totalPark <= minToHours(40)){
            return `Your parking fee is only £${4}.`
        }

        else if(totalPark > minToHours(40) && totalPark <= minToHours(60)){
            return `Your parking fee is only £${6}.`
        }
        else if(totalPark > minToHours(60) && totalPark <= minToHours(120)){
            return `Your parking fee is only £${7}.`
        }
        else if(totalPark > minToHours(120) && totalPark <= minToHours(180)){
            return `Your parking fee is only £${9}.`
        }
        else if(totalPark > minToHours(180) && totalPark <= minToHours(240)){
            return `Your parking fee is only £${11}.`
        }
        else if(totalPark > minToHours(240) && totalPark <= minToHours(480)){
            return `Your fparking fee is only £${13}.`
        }
      
        else if(totalPark > minToHours(480) && totalPark < minToHours(1440)){
            
            return `Your parking fee is only £${15}.`
        }

        else if(totalPark > minToHours(1440) && totalPark < minToHours(2880)){
            
            return `Your parking fee is only £${16}.`
        }

        //if totalPark > 24 HRS

        else {

            totalPrice = add24HR(totalPark, penaltyFee)

        }

        return totalPrice;

    }

    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = (parkingFees("5/12/2020 18:30", "5/18/2020 18:30"))
```

Comment: Hey, just took a quick look at your code and noticed you used `arr = new Array()` defining arrays that way is not a good practice whatsoever in js, so instead use `arr = []`

Comment: What makes you think that this case is not efficient? What do you mean by efficient?

Comment: @tgdavies It's long, not "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself),  which makes it harder to maintain. Efficiency is not only about computing performance, it's also how easily you can read the code again in 5 years and modify it

Comment: I believe this would be a better question for the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), especially with a more precise definition of efficient (I'm guessing you mean that the code is way too verbose and repeats itself everywhere?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor it to use an Array. Then, if the fees change, you don't need to fiddle around in your code, you can just change the price in that Array:

```js
const steps = [
  { limit:       20, fee:  2 }, // The limits are in minutes
  { limit:       40, fee:  4 },
  { limit:       60, fee:  6 },
  { limit:   2 * 60, fee:  7 },
  { limit:   3 * 60, fee:  9 },
  { limit:   4 * 60, fee: 11 },
  { limit:   8 * 60, fee: 13 },
  { limit:  24 * 60, fee: 15 }, // For complex rules, use a function:
  { limit: Infinity, fee: minutes => 9 * Math.ceil(minutes / 24 / 60) + 7 }
];

// Converts a date string to a number of minutes since 1970-01-01
const dateToMinutes = str => Math.floor(new Date(str).getTime() / 60000);

const calcFee = (parkingDate, returnDate) => {
  const minutesParked = dateToMinutes(returnDate) - dateToMinutes(parkingDate);
  for (let step of steps) {
    if (minutesParked <= step.limit) {
      return isNaN(step.fee) ? step.fee(minutesParked) : step.fee;
    }
  }
};

// Just for testing
const test = (x, y) => (document.body.innerHTML += `<p>${x} - ${y}<br><b>${formatDuration(x, y)}: €${calcFee(x, y)}</b></p>`); const formatDuration = (x, y) => { const d = dateToMinutes(y) - dateToMinutes(x); const res = {d: Math.floor(d / 24 / 60), h: Math.floor((d % (24 * 60)) / 60), m: d % 60}; return `${res.d} days ${res.h} hours ${res.m} min`; };

test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-12 18:40:00");
test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-12 19:00:00");
test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-12 19:30:00");
test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-13 18:29:00");
test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-13 18:31:00");
test("2020-05-12 18:30:00", "2020-05-18 18:30:00");
```

Comment: Incredible answer! Thanks!